# Python - how to copy selected text to clip board in windows

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program on simulate human operation on Windows.

I find problem in the "Copy" operation: Select some content on windows and "copy the selected content into clip board".

Most of the methods suggests to use the hotkey "Ctrl+C" but the hotkey doesn't work to copy the selected content in some software like XShell.

Is there any other solution?

Thank you.

Comment: From my understanding of windows this is not possible without sending key strokes. The app itself handles the keystrokes for ctrl + c and it also handles highlighting text. If you highlight text it doesn't automatically go to the clipboard. You program has to handle the highlighted text. The only other option I can think of for you is to simulate a right click and then select copy?

Comment: Try `ctrl + shift + c` or mouse middle click to copy, and `ctrl + shift + v` or mouse right click to paste. (`ctrl + v`) if you want to paste within another program